# Trying to implement multiple CSS Only Tab Groups on the same page

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have been overcoming so many issues trying to implement multiple tab groups on a page. Code Pen has great patterns for putting one group of tabs on a page. But I have not found a pattern that does this for multiple tab groups on a page using only CSS and no JS. Here is what I have attempted so far. But I get issues with the height.

```css
.tabs input[type=radio] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
  }
  .tabs {
   
   float: none;
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 75px auto;
  }
  .tabs li{
   float: left;
  }
  .tabs label {
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
   color: #08C;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-family: 'Roboto', helveti;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
   top: 3px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  .tabs label:hover {
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   top: 0;
  }

  [id^=tab]:checked + label {
   background: #08C;
   color: white;
   top: 0;
  }

  [id^=tab]:checked ~ .rel-container > [id^=tab-content] {
   display: block;
  }
  .tab-content{
   z-index: 2;
   display: none;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 140%;
   padding-top: 10px;
   background: #08C;
   padding: 15px;
   color: white;
   position: absolute;
   top: 53px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
   -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
   -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
   animation-duration: 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
     <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
     <label for="tab1">tab 1</label>
     <div class="rel-container">
     <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
     <label for="tab2">tab 2</label>
     <div class="rel-container">
     <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
     <label for="tab3">tab 3</label>
     <div class="rel-container">
     <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"

      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="main">
   <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
     <input type="radio" checked name="tabs1" id="tab4">
     <label for="tab4">tab 4</label>
     <div class="rel-container">
     <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="radio" name="tabs1" id="tab5">
     <label for="tab5">tab 5</label>
     <div class="rel-container">
     <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="radio" name="tabs1" id="tab6">
     <label for="tab6">tab 6</label>
     <div class="rel-container">
     <div id="tab-content6" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
     </div>
    </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

What are the adjustments in my code that can make this implementation possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't understand your requirement clearly but yet I analyzed your code and found that you want to use same code for multiple tabbing functionality on a same page. (Correct me if I am wrong.) Below is a solution for this scenario only.

I think you should give width to wrapper element. In your code it is `.main` class.
I have used `float: left` css property to get it correct way visually.

CSS Addition:

```
.main {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

May you need to write more CSS for responsive views.

For reference I have created [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kutec/7xzcowsq/).

Answer (score 1):

Since the tab-content elements have `position: absolute`, they have no actual height in the stack order. This causes content below to collapse up. The tabs li elements have a `float: left`, so they all stack up next to each other.

For this to work, you will need to set a height on the `ul.tabs` container that is tall enough to accommodate the tallest tab. This is obviously not ideal, because the length of the content in each `tab-content`could change. To get around this, you'd either need to find a way to position the `tab-content` elements relatively, or use JavaScript to dynamically set the height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

For a PURE CSS solution, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emerinohdz/af6s6L8h/).

The solution involves setting `position: absolute` and static widths on `.tabs label`, then position them using the `left` property. You DON'T need to set a static height on `.tab-content` divs, just change postion to relative.

You can use the same technique if you need more than one row of tabs.